# Heltec WiFi Kit 32 and PlaftormIO configuration (baud rate?)

Tags: esp32, platform-io

I am just getting started with PlatformIO and have chosen a [Heltec WiFi Kit 32](https://heltec.org/project/wifi-kit-32/).

I loaded the PlatformIO demo `espidf-http-request`, built it and loaded it, but the serial terminal shows

> �␄@�␀␙␔␄␔␀�␀ @���H␂␐␀␀␄␀``` ␀␀␀   ␎0␀␀�␒
>   bd␋�␒␔Q� �␀␕��bH�A�Pb(,␒�0�␒P␀␒���Ȑ2<U�␄␂�  ␄␓␒"␃␀``␀��PI␅ "J␆I�␄␀��␀�2,␑$�␌B ```␁␄+����

which seems to be a baud rate problem.

My platformio.ini contains

> [env:heltec_wifi_kit_32]
>   platform = espressif32
>   board =
>   heltec_wifi_kit_32
>   framework = espidf
>   monitor_port  = COM3
>   monitor_speed = 115200
>   upload_port = COM3
>   upload_speed = 115200

any idea what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps anyone ...

74880 baud works and I see output.

BUT, I have to Ctrl-c in PlatformIO’s terminal and issue the command
platformio device monitor --baud 74880

that means that I miss output from the startup sequence.

Why does the build not honour the platformion.ini file and its monitor_speed entry? I would expect that to generate some code in the hidden main() function to set the baud rate.

Oh, well, it's an imprefect solution, but it' a sort of solution